# Visual Studio. Конфигурация сборки проекта

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я написал две программы. Одну на Java, вторую на C# с абсолютно одинаковым содержимым, чтобы просто сравнить производительность. Результаты были удивительными. После этого я обратился к преподавателю, чтобы выяснить, в чем дело (шарповский код выполнялся в 8 (!!!) раз дольше). На его машине (VS 2008) он переключил с Debug на Release в студии, после чего время выполнения программы сократилось в 3 раза. Я пришел домой и тот же трюк не сработал (VS 2013).

В общем, ищу совета по профилям в Visual Studio. Как "включить оптимизацию"?

Код шарпа:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BoxingTest
{
    public abstract class BoxedVal
    {
        public abstract BoxedVal Add(BoxedVal other);
        public abstract bool LessThan(BoxedVal other);
        public abstract bool GreaterThan(BoxedVal other);
    }

    public class BoxedInt : BoxedVal
    {
        public int Value;

        public BoxedInt(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public override BoxedVal Add(BoxedVal other)
        {
            BoxedInt i = other as BoxedInt;
            return new BoxedInt(Value + i.Value);
        }

        public override bool LessThan(BoxedVal other)
        {
            BoxedInt i = other as BoxedInt;
            return Value < i.Value;
        }

        public override bool GreaterThan(BoxedVal other)
        {
            BoxedInt i = other as BoxedInt;
            return Value > i.Value;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static int Fib(int nn)
        {
            BoxedVal one = new BoxedInt(1);

            BoxedVal a = one;
            BoxedVal b = one;

            BoxedVal n = new BoxedInt(nn);

            BoxedVal thousand = new BoxedInt(1000);

            for (BoxedVal i = new BoxedInt(2); i.LessThan(n); i = i.Add(one))
            {
                BoxedVal c = a.Add(b);
                a = b;
                b = c;

                if (b.GreaterThan(thousand))
                {
                    a = one;
                    b = one;
                }
            }
            return (b as BoxedInt).Value;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int times = 5;
            int n = 20000000;

            int total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            {
                var start = DateTime.Now;
                int val = Fib(n);

                int dt = (DateTime.Now - start).Milliseconds;
                total += dt;
                Console.WriteLine(val);
                Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0} ms", dt);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Average: {0} ms", total / times);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Код на Java:

```
abstract class BoxedVal
{
    public abstract BoxedVal Add(BoxedVal other);
    public abstract boolean LessThan(BoxedVal other);
    public abstract boolean GreaterThan(BoxedVal other);
}


class BoxedInt extends BoxedVal
{
    public int Value;


    public BoxedInt(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public BoxedVal Add(BoxedVal other)
    {
        BoxedInt i = (BoxedInt)other;
        return new BoxedInt(Value + i.Value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean LessThan(BoxedVal other)
    {
        BoxedInt i = (BoxedInt)other;
        return Value < i.Value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean GreaterThan(BoxedVal other)
    {
        BoxedInt i = (BoxedInt)other;
        return Value > i.Value;
    }
}

public class BoxingTest {

    private static int Fib(int nn)
    {
        BoxedVal one = new BoxedInt(1);

        BoxedVal a = one;
        BoxedVal b = one;

        BoxedVal n = new BoxedInt(nn);

        BoxedVal thousand = new BoxedInt(1000);

        for (BoxedVal i = new BoxedInt(2); i.LessThan(n); i = i.Add(one))
        {
            BoxedVal c = a.Add(b);
            a = b;
            b = c;

            if (b.GreaterThan(thousand))
            {
                a = one;
                b = one;
            }
        }
        return ((BoxedInt)b).Value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int times = 5;
        int n = 20000000;

        long total = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i<times;i++){
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            int val = Fib(n);
            long dt = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            total+= dt;
            System.out.println(val);
            System.out.println("Elapsed: "+dt+" ms");
        }

        System.out.println("Average: "+(total/times)+" ms");

    }
}
```

Comment: Давайте код, тогда можно ещё о чем-то говорить.

Comment: Код добавил, но я очень сомневаюсь, что дело именно в нём :)

Comment: попробуйте юзать Stopwatch вместо DateTime.
Ну и в C# вместо `as` попробуйте директ каст.

BoxedInt i = other as BoxedInt; -> var i = (BoxedInt)other;

Comment: профилировщик непрозрачно намекает, что дело совсем не в DateTime. БОльшую часть времени работает clr.dll (99.2%), но я попробую ^_^

Comment: На самом деле использование `DateTime.Now` в C# и, скорее всего `System.currentTimeMillis()` дает совершенно левые результаты. В C# стоит использовать `Stopwatch.StartNew()` (это **значительно** меняет результаты измерений в этом примере). И стоит поискать его аналог в Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, Вы запускаете Ваше приложение кнопкой **F5** - Start Debugging,
а Ваш преподаватель **Ctrl + F5** - Start Without Debugging.

У меня C#-код выполняется следующее время

- Debug, с отладчиком: 756ms
- Debug, без отладчика: 989ms
- Release, с отладчиком: 844ms
- Release, без отладчика: 388ms

Java-код выполняется

- Release (Run): 159ms
- Debug: 174ms

**UPDATE**:
Забавно, увеличил константу до 200 000 000 (в 10 раз).

Теперь C# "обгоняет": Average: 863 ms

Java: Average: 1296 ms

Comment: Интересно, какой результат будет, если убрать строгую типизацию и понатыкать var'ов?...

Comment: А еще можно попробовать using(xxx){} понатыкать... Тоже было интересно...

Comment: Я запускал с разными конфигами (включая конфиги с отключенным дебагом). И получился примерно тот же результат, что и у Вас, поэтому я и задался этим вопросом.
Меня терзают смутные сомнения... Я тоже попробовал увеличить константу в 10 раз и поучил ПРИРОСТ в производительности на C# О_о 328 мс изначальных, против 214 мс после увеличения константы в 10 раз. Такое ощущение, что я написал что-то неправильно, хотя программы зеркальны... Что касается Java, то увеличение константы ведет за собой логичное увеличение времени работы.

Comment: @Sharbag, только не `var`, а `dynamic`. `var` просто выводит тип, как `auto` в `С++`. А `using` скорее всего выкинет оптимизатор. Ни ресурсов, ни исключений же нет.

Comment: @Toisen, Думаю, чтобы понять, почему так отличается скорость, нужно разбираться в настройках Runtime-среды. Как настроена сборка мусора, как настроено кэширование результатов. Как настроен JIT. В общем, рантайм - та еще глубокая яма.

Comment: @WalterNuss, точно такой же. var -- это просто сахар, который заменяется во время компиляции и не влияет на выполнение.